# CuPy CUDA - Failed to Import CuPy

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I have installed the correct version of CuPy with pip install cupy-cuda117 on pyCharms as my CUDA is version 11.7. My Python version is 3.8. I also have the environment variables set but I am still receiving this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\PycharmProjects\Project_Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cupy import _core  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\PycharmProjects\Project_Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\cupy\_core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
  File "cupy\_core\core.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core.core
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\PycharmProjects\Project_Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\PycharmProjects\Project_Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import device
  File "cupy\cuda\device.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.device
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing runtime: The specified module could not be found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dominic/PycharmProjects/Project_Trading/regression_to_classification.py", line 77, in <module>
    import cupy
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\PycharmProjects\Project_Trading\venv\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise ImportError(f'''
ImportError: 
================================================================
Failed to import CuPy.

If you installed CuPy via wheels (cupy-cudaXXX or cupy-rocm-X-X), make sure that the package matches with the version of CUDA or ROCm installed.

On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm.
On Windows, try setting CUDA_PATH environment variable.

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

Original error:
  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing runtime: The specified module could not be found.
================================================================


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is some additional info:

[image: nvcc --version]

[image: environment variables]

[image: pip freeze]

[image: windows specs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into something similar when trying to install `cupy` recently. These are the steps that ultimately resulted in the import error:

1. Try to `pip install cupy`.
2. Realize that this is taking too long and/or requires a compiler etc.
3. Stop the install/build.
4. Install one of the prebuilt wheels (e.g. `pip install cupy-cuda11x`).
5. Notice that the `cupy` package is somehow installed (probably a remnant from the first stage).
6. `pip uninstall cupy` to get rid of the `cupy` library which shouldn't be there. **<< This is the stage that causes the problem!**

The last step above breaks whichever mappings the wheel installer creates that allow one to `import cupy` despite installing a package called e.g. `cupy-cuda11x`.

The solution that worked for me was to remove all `cupy*` packages and install **only** the wheel distribution. In the case shown in the question, reinstalling `cupy-cuda11x` should do the trick.